# How could I call a function as a pointer from an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

So Im using an array of structs like so:

```
struct node
{
  char* name;
  int   value;
};

node *nodeArray = new node*[50];
```

Im trying to call a function from the array so I can search through the elements like so:

```
struct node* newNode;
newNode = nodeArray->find(name);
```

if name was a char* so it returns a pointer to the node in the array once the name is found.

How would I go about creating a class to call a find function from the array?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The variable name `newNode` is pretty confusing, do you want to find an existing node, and let the function create a new one if it's not found? Also you don't need a class for this necessarily, you could well create a free `find()` function, that operates on `nodeArray` passed as a parameter.

Comment: `node *nodeArray = new node*[50];` has a type mismatch.

Comment: Arrays can't have member functions, so you can't do `nodeArray->find(name)`. It would have to be `find(nodeArray, name)`.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would solve it, if you insist on using a node array class.
Note that I assume that `node` is declared like in the original post.

```
#include <vector>

class NodeArray
{
public:
    explicit NodeArray(size_t length)
        : nodes_(length)
    {}

    Node* find(const char* name){
        for (size_t i = 0; i != nodes_.size(); ++i){
            if (0 == strcmp(nodes_[i].name, name)){ // strcmp is not pretty though.
                return &(nodes_[i]);
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }

    // TODO: add methods for filling/accessing the nodes..

private:
    std::vector<node> nodes_;
};

int main()
{
    NodeArray my_nodes(50);
    // do stuff
    node* some_node = my_nodes.find("some");
    if (some_node) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: If you already use a `std::vector` this could be used in 1st place as well, and an appropriate `std::find()` call with a lambda function would serve with a load less lines of code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Which makes my answer not useful? I doubt that. Also, if the OT should want more control over his node array, he would need to write his own class anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this little "hack". It will work because `NodeArray` has no data members and no virtual functions, so you just convert first `node` address to pointer to `NodeArray` and call `find` function. Find function will get the first node address as `this` pointer.

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
  char* name;
  int   value;
};

class NodeArray {

public:

    node* find(const char* name, int len) {

        node* current = (node*)this;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; current++) {

            if (current->name && !strcmp(current->name, name)) return current;

        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    node* get(int index) {

        return ((node*)this) + index;

    }

};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    NodeArray* node_array = (NodeArray*) (new node[50]);

    node_array->get(10)->name = "blabla";

    if (node_array->find("blabla", 50)) {

        std::cout << "FOUND!";

    }

    delete [] ((node*)node_array);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, you should never write code like that. That´s just hazardous.

Comment: @BetaCarotin: it allows you to do some very nice tricky things, have it from HotSpot sources, but you are right, it is hazardous